# Limpieza de paquetes dependencias de compilación en Debian 9

Tags: bash, servidor, debian, optimización, compilar

Tengo un script para compilar varios programas de un servidor LEMP (nginx, php, openssl, etc...), me gustaria saber que paquetes podría eliminar luego de finalizar con las compilaciones.

Dejo los fragmentos de código donde hago la instalación y limpieza de paquetes dentro del script.

## Instalación de paquetes

```
    # TODO: check this: Packages that can be deleted after the script is finished.

    apt-get -y install libxau-dev libxdmcp-dev xorg-sgml-doctools \
    libexpat1-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl \
    docbook-xml needrestart autoconf \
    automake m4 bison \
    build-essential g++ pkg-config \
    autotools-dev libtool expect \
    libcunit1-dev x11proto-core-dev file \
    libenchant-dev libjemalloc-dev gnu-standards \
    autoconf-archive g++-multilib gcc-multilib \
    libstdc++-6-dev gcc-6-locales \
    g++-6-multilib valgrind valgrind-mpi \
    valkyrie gcj-jdk flex \
    tk-dev libc-ares-dev

    # TODO: check this: Important packages that must be installed.

    apt-get -y install coreutils binutils uuid-dev wget \
    mcrypt libmcrypt-dev cython \
    perl libpcre3 libpcre3-dev  \
    libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev \
    libtiffxx5 libjpeg62-turbo-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev \
    libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev \
    libjansson-dev \
    libgmp-dev libev-dev libevent-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev libgdbm-dev libdb-dev \
    libsystemd-dev libspdylay-dev \
    libaio-dev libncurses5-dev \
    libunistring-dev libunbound-dev \
    trousers libidn2-0 \
    libicu-dev libltdl-dev libpspell-dev libreadline-dev \
    libc6-dev libc-dbg libpam0g-dev libmsgpack-dev libstemmer-dev libbsd-dev \
    gettext debian-keyring liblinear-tools liblinear-dev \
    libdbi-perl libboost-all-dev rsync net-tools libdbd-mysql-perl \
    re2c libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev qt4-qmake libqt4-dev \
    libssl-dev golang python-dev python3-dev python-setuptools
```

## Limpieza de paquetes

```
apt-get -y remove libxau-dev libxdmcp-dev xorg-sgml-doctools \
libexpat1-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl \
docbook-xml needrestart autoconf \
automake m4 bison \
build-essential g++ pkg-config \
autotools-dev libtool expect \
libcunit1-dev x11proto-core-dev file \
libenchant-dev libjemalloc-dev gnu-standards \
autoconf-archive g++-multilib gcc-multilib \
libstdc++-6-dev gcc-6-locales \
g++-6-multilib valgrind valgrind-mpi \
valkyrie gcj-jdk flex \
tk-dev libc-ares-dev

apt-get -y autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Supongo que es una buena práctica hacer este tipo de limpieza, podría limpiar todos los paquetes que sus nombres terminan en -dev. ¿O esto podría afectar algo?

Gracias.

Comment: Gracias por avisarme, ya lo he hecho. Espero que se entienda mi pregunta. Saludos.